# Undefined control sequence in R Markdown from \frac{}{}

Tags: errors, rmarkdown

I am a beginner working in R markdown. I can compile the given minimally reproducible example below as an HTML. But, when I try to compile the RMD file as a PDF, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.76   considering whether \(U \lt
                                   \frac{2 f(Z)}{3 g(Z)}\) 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Untitled.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Untitled.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I have updated all my packages, following the guidance of the URL given in the error message. I still get the same error message. I tried moving the example into overleaf and got a similar problem. The syntax \frac{}{} should have a defined control sequence -- I use it all the time without error.

Here's the minimally reproducible example of my problem:

```
---
title: "test"
author: "author"
date: "9/23/2021"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
header-includes: \usepackage{amsmath}
---
 (2) considering whether $U \lt \frac{2 f(Z)}{3 g(Z)}$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How  or where is `\lt` defined?

Comment: Thanks, I think \lt  is the "less than" operator, but I guess that is my mistake..?

Comment: Yeah, the undefined control sequence is the last element of the first line, not the first element of the second line.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not `\frac`, but `\lt`. Assuming `\lt` refers to `l`ess `t`han, just use

```
$U < \frac{2 f(Z)}{3 g(Z)}$
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Any intuition for why?

Comment: @AlecPaulson: Under `$`...`$` in markdown there is a switch to use (La)TeX definitions, and `\lt` isn't defined by default. HTML provides `&lt;` but that doesn't necessarily translate to `\lt` in (La)TeX.